# Is it possible to create a table from Paragraph fields in Views?

Tags: views, entities

I'm trying to create a table in Views with the information from a node that is using Paragraphs. Somehow I can't find a way to display the values from the paragraph fields in a proper table, is this even possible?
All I can manage to do is the table as shown in the picture below:[image: I would like for each paragraph field to get its own column.]

If possible, how can I create a table where each field has its own column instead? And if that's not possible – what other approach should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enhance your view with Relationships.

Let's say you have a content type *Client* with a paragraphs field *Mail*, which allows embedding instances of the paragraphs bundle *Client_Mail*. When you create a view on all Client nodes, you should find a Relationship to the field (Mail) which contains your paragraph bundle (Client_Mail). 
After adding this relationship, the fields making up the paragraphs bundle will show up in the field list. You can add and arrange them like regular node fields, but make sure that the paragraphs relation is chosen in the field settings.